# Can't hear sound on Instagram or Vine videos when using Chrome or Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, audio

I can see Vine and Instagram videos, but there is no sound. Even if I click the speaker on a Vine to unmute it I don't get sound. I have the newest version of Chrome, and I don't have any problems with sound on other sites like YouTube. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

You probably have a creative sound board so click start, control panel, Audio control panel, speakers tab, change from 7.1 to 2/2.1 speakers. Then reload instagram. 
Your Welcome!

Comment: Not only Creative ones: I faced the same problem and seems that the video player doesn't sound when configured in any sound system other than stereo. I have an integrated sound card and happened to be the same, when set it to stereo everything was fine.

Comment: Heh. *You’re* welcome.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click on a video
2. Right click while the video is playing/paused and then click unmute.

So that's it, the vine videos should have sounds now. :D

Comment: I don't know How, But the trick works Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Realtek Cards require stereo mixing to be enabled. This requires their most up to date driver. Get that driver now.
2. Once driver is installed:
3. Go to Start.
4. Control Panel.
5. Sound
6. Click Recording Tab.
7. Right click under the list of shown devices.
8. Click "Show Disabled Devices"
9. Stereo Mixing should now be on the list.
10. Click Stereo Mixing, or Right Click and select "enable"

work for me

Answer (score -1):

I lost the audio on Instagram with the upgrade from Windows 7 to Win 10.

I typed Audio Control Panel into Cortana and selected Creative Audio Control Panel. (Remember this is Sound Card Specific).

I selected speaker configuration under speakers (it may default to that) and changed the setting to 2/2.1 speakers.

It worked immediately with no reboot!

This is a variant of a previous answer that worked for me.

Thank you, Any!

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve the problem by changing sound mode from "5.1" to Stereo in the Audio Driver Software (in my case in the Sound Manager of Realtek HD).

Answer (score -2):

I'm on mac and had somehow muted the whole site.

To unmute: right-click on the instagram tab and select 'Unmute Site'

[image]